# How can we port addGestureRecognizer( recognizer ) for WKInterfaceController

Tags: animation, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

Below code is implemented using viewController can i do same thing for Apple Watch and add animation?

```
let filteredSubviews = self.view.subviews.filter({ $0.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) })// 2
    for view in filteredSubviews  {
        // 3
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleTap:"))
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1
        // 4
        recognizer.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        returnedAray=tempArray
        //TODO: Add a custom gesture recognizer too
    }
```

I just need to know what is alternative of addGestureRecognizer(recognizer) for WatchKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do gesture recognizers or touch events in an Apple Watch App.

Comment: so what can we do for tapping in WatchKit?

Comment: You can add buttons and tables to your Watch App and respond to the user tapping on the button or table cell.  You can also add a menu to your app that is activated on a force press.  Remember that the code for Watch Apps are not native apps.  They are extensions running on an iPhone.  The actual Watch App is just UI.

Answer (score 6):

You can not use gesture recognizers in Watch applications.

But you can use WKInterfaceButton with context "Group" instead of "text":

[image]

So button will contain any group and you can implement ***action*** on tapping.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Button contains group with image and label.

Comment: please answer relevant to question :/

Comment: 2 Samrez Ikram: It is impossible to use gesture recognizers. WKInterfaceObject is NOT a UIResonder or UIView. But you can create a BIG WKInterfaceButton (fullscreen, transparent, e.t.c.) and handle tapping on button. Choose context = "Group" and fill any content to this group :)

Comment: You also can use WKInterfaceTable and handle tapping on cell with 
    -(void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex